# How to configure varnish to cache on local disk instead of memory?

Tags: php, html, caching, varnish

Varnish is powerful cache server and needs a lot of memory space 
In Wordpress there's a plugin called wp-super cache I use it in many application it is similar to varnish as it can cache entire HTML response 
But it's use local disk to store caches 
How to make varnish act in similar way so cache content is stored on local disk without consuming memory?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/130185/store-varnish-cache-in-hard-disk

Comment: This good answer    This means that memory is used to load cache from local disk. I thought cache only depends on memory.  Thanks